# Best shortest way to set value in c# class

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. Here i want to set value of `Root` class and also with all its child list value. I already tried like bellow but i was able to do it for `Root` but how can i set value for all inside child class?

Model Class:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{

    public class Child3
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public List<Child3> children { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public List<Child2> children { get; set; }
    }
    public class Root
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public List<Child> children { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Trying to set value:

```
var root = new List<Root>();


    root.Add(new Root
    {
        Id = 1,
        text = "foo",
        children = new List<Child>()
        {
            //i am not getting idea from here.
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take full advantage of C#'s [object and collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

First, consider updating your models to automatically instantiate their lists. For example:

```
public class Root
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Child> children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}
```

Note that the `children` property is initialized with an empty list. Now you can easily specify the collection items inside your object initialization code.

```
var root = new List<Root>
{
    new Root 
    {
        Id = 1,
        text = "foo",
        children = 
        {
            new Child 
            {
               // ...
            },

            new Child 
            {
               // ...
            },
        }
    }
};
```

If you do not want to have your collections automatically instantiated, you will need to instantiate them at each level:

```
var root = new List<Root>
{
    new Root 
    {
        Id = 1,
        text = "foo",
        children = new List<Child>
        {
            new Child 
            {
               // ...
            },

            new Child 
            {
               // ...
            },
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var root = new List<Root>();


    root.Add(new Root
    {
        Id = 1,
        text = "foo",
        children = new List<Child>()
        {
            new Child
            {...},
            new Child
            {...},
            new Child
            {...}
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you are stuck on should have a bunch of `Child`ren, so create a bunch of `Child` objects!

```
children = new List<Child>
{
    new Child {
        ...
    },

    new Child {
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Inside each `Child` object, you continue the pattern on:

```
new Child {
    Id = ...,
    Text = ...,
    children = new List<Child2> {
        new Child2 { ... },
        new Child2 { ... },
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var root = new List<Root>();
root.Add(new Root
{
    Id = 1,
    text = "foo",
    children = new List<Child>()
    {

        new Child{
            Id = 1,
            text = "child text",
            children = new List<Child2>(){
                new Child2{
                    Id = 1,
                    text = "child text",
                    children =  new List<Child3>{
                        new Child3{
                            Id =1,
                            text = "child text"
                        },
                        new Child3{
                            Id =2,
                            text = "child text"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Child2{
                    Id = 2,
                    text = "child text",
                    children =  new List<Child3>{
                        new Child3{
                            Id =3,
                            text = "child text"
                        },
                        new Child3{
                            Id =4,
                            text = "child text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        //Child 2
       new Child{
            Id = 1,
            text = "child text",
            children = new List<Child2>(){
                new Child2{
                    Id = 1,
                    text = "child text",
                    children =  new List<Child3>{
                        new Child3{
                            Id =1,
                            text = "child text"
                        },
                        new Child3{
                            Id =2,
                            text = "child text"
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Child2{
                    Id = 2,
                    text = "child text",
                    children =  new List<Child3>{
                        new Child3{
                            Id =3,
                            text = "child text"
                        },
                        new Child3{
                            Id =4,
                            text = "child text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    },
});
```